# Two identical functions in Alpine.store yield different results

Tags: alpine.js

I have two identical functions in an Alpine store, differing only by their name.

```
Alpine.store('collection', {
  var1: false,
  var2: 1,
  functionA() {
    alert(this.var1)
    alert(this.var2)
  },
  functionB() {
    alert(this.var1)
    alert(this.var2)
  }
}

<!-- in the html -->

<body x-data>
  <button @click="$store.collection.functionA">Button</button>
  <button @click="$store.collection.functionB">Button</button>
</body>
```

When each is called, the variables in Function A are undefined but the variables in FunctionB return with the correct values.

The declared order does not, and should not, make a difference.

I have also tried swapping the @clicks on the buttons calling these methods. No matter what, the variables in FunctionA are always undefined.

I can't see any logical reason why the properties referenced in functionA are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are actually not using the store and at the same time you also have a global `functionB` function. In order to call a function in the store, you need to use the [`$store` global object](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/store).

```
<body x-data>
  <button @click="$store.collection.functionA()">Button</button>
  <button @click="$store.collection.functionB()">Button</button>
</body>
```

Comment: The example in my post was wrong. I was actually referencing the functions in the store with the same described result. Still not sure why it does not work correctly. I have updated the example in my post.

Comment: It's not working because you are still not calling the function. See my answer: `@click="$store.collection.functionA()"`, note the parenthesis at the end.